# How do I create a loop for subreports?

Tags: jasper-reports, subreport

Adding a subreport into a report with Java and Jasper Reports was easy enough, but I am having trouble making that subreport into something loopable.

The code in Java was simple enough: create report and loop through the parameters to generate subreports. The report generated at the end is a XLS file.

The hassle starts with Jasper Reports since the second iteration complains about the subreport datasource ID already being in use, but then if I generate dynamically the names in the Java code, the Jasper Report won't compile since the subreport's database name is fixed in the XML.

I could, in theory, just create several of the reports with a single subreport and then attach all of them together, but that doesn't feel optimal. How can I create the looped reports then? Is it some sort of parameter to be given in the XML from Jasper Reports or is it impossible to be done and I must use the multiple reports strategy instead?

Comment: Sorry it really hard to understand what you are trying to achieve, probably your are on the wrong path. It would be nice if you could display the expected output in a [mcve]. This is probably a [x-y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Are you using some dynamic jasper library (dynamic-reports or dynamic-jasper)?

Comment: Hmm... I didn't add any code since what I have to code in Java ends up being very simple: "Report report = new Report("REPORT", parameters)". I didn't really think about dynamic jasper libraries, but that did make me go looking around further in the code.

Comment: My class was extending from another class, which was abstracting from another that was using the net.sf.jasperreports.engine library. It ends up being that the limitation I fell through was due to the abstracted class since the "REPORT" above was doing the checks on the datasource names (and thus the message for the ID already being in use when I had a looping for creating new reports with the same ID). But unless I create the XML dynamically to add the datasource names for each subreport, it feels thatI will be stuck on attaching all subreports together.